# How AWS-RDS handle one million request per second

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an API service that'll handle one million requests per second I am using the lambda function and Aws Rds for database storage I want to know how to handle 1 million reads and write queries per second which RDS setting will be feasible for this scenario

**I am currently using 1TB gp2 with auto-scaling
How can we count read/write IOPS how do we know we need more IOPS or storage?
how Aws-Rds autoscaling when millions of requests come?**

Comment: Please don't make number of sub-questions in your question. Focus on one specific issue that you have (not multiple of them), and provide all details relevant to that one single issue.

Comment: Are you seeing an actual problem now, or are you wondering about a hypothetical future?

Comment: This is a practical question I am working toward upgrading my current system to handle heavy traffic(one million requests or queries per sec).